# async/await in .NET 4.0: a Compatibe Set of DLLs?

Tags: c#, .net, .net-4.0, async-await, c#-5.0

I would like to use `async`/`await` syntax when targeting .NET FX 4.0.

I fetched the [`Microsoft.Bcl.Async.1.0.168`](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Bcl.Async) Nuget package.
 It has the assembly `Microsoft.Threading.Tasks, Version=1.0.12.0` 
which implements all the magic and has a reference to `System.Runtime, Version=1.5.11.0`.

The `System.Runtime` assembly is available in the companion Nuget package `Microsoft.Bcl.1.1.8`, but has a different version `2.6.8.0` in there.

As a result, its usages won't compile without special tricks and hacks.
The DLL reference does not resolve because of the version number mismatch.

So, is it possible to get a consistent set of *BCL Async* DLLs which reference one another by matching version numbers and which can be compiled right away?

*(Tried looking in other Nuget versions or other target ilb folders, found some matching versions but they're for a different platform and with a different set of classes, e.g. with a duplicate `Task` class)*

UPD: Also mind the runtime behavior: with netfx45, these assemblies get unified into runtime and work like a charm, but on a vanilla netfx40 system you'd get a `System.IO.FileLoadException` with `Could not load file or assembly 'System.Threading.Tasks, Version=1.5.11.0, […]`

Comment: Have you tried [assembly redirection](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/7wd6ex19.aspx "Redirecting Assembly Versions")?

Comment: Used that technique previously and see no reason why this hack won't work to save the runtime. But it's only for EXEs, and I'm making a DLL which is about to be loaded into multiple hosts, in which case there's no consistent way of supplying the appconfig. Anyway that's the means for addressing updated versions, and for just the baseline code I pretty much would like to have compatible baseline versions.

Answer (score 1):

All you need is the one Nuget package, and VS2012 or higher. (with Nuget 2.3 or higher) 
https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Bcl.Async

Nuget will install all dependencies with the correct version (unless you specify otherwise). I've done this many times, and I'll tell you right now you only need to use that one package, and if its not working there is something else wrong with your setup.

If you don't have VS2012, you can download the Express (free) version in order to use this.

If my word isnt enough, you can read the official MSDN blog on the subject. 
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/bclteam/archive/2012/10/22/using-async-await-without-net-framework-4-5.aspx 
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/bclteam/archive/2013/04/17/microsoft-bcl-async-is-now-stable.aspx

Comment: Nope, won't do. First, it's two packages with DLLs (`Microsoft.Bcl` referenced). Second, they got a version-incompatible set of DLLs, as described above. But there's the third nuget in the set which carries some sheer black magic DLL and .targets files which would trick the build into looking over the version diff. Thing is, I'm wondering if it's possible to get a straight build without the magic, 'cause it might get costly to scale on the whole environment.

Comment: Also, having those versions incompatible it might crash at runtime with a FileLoadException. With netfx45 it gets unified into runtime OK, but on a vanilla netfx40 machine it's _Could not load file or assembly 'System.Threading.Tasks, Version=1.5.11.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)_

Comment: @hypersw: The hacks are necessary to make it work; there's no way to do a "straight build without the magic". Nuget will add the appropriate assembly redirects. Regarding the vanilla net40: these packages do not support vanilla net40; you need at least KB2468871.

Comment: Stephen: Nuget won't save the runtime. Anyway, is there any strong reason for the hacks to be needed, but for the version numbers being inconsistent across the DLL set?